# Control-L shortcut in input field on OS X, what is it for?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I accidentally found that if you select some text in input box on OS X and hit <kbd>^</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> this text flashes in yellow but nothing else happens.

You can try it in your browser's location bar. I use Chrome but I think it works in Safari too. Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to select the text in location bar and then <kbd>^</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to make it flash.

Any ideas what is it for?

Comment: look at keyboard shortcuts in prefs. Just guessing: that's what it does. It helps you figure out which input box is selected.

Comment: It does not work when no text is selected. So if this is a way to highlight the selected input box it's very limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In multiline input fields, it is used to [center the selection](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/System%20Bindings.html).

Before (top) and after (bottom):

[image: before]
[image: after]

The highlighting is done to make it stick out, just like with Safari search results on a page (Cmd-F/Cmd-G).